# Array is filled with 4 items but length is 0

Tags: javascript, android, ios, arrays, reactjs

I'm using javascript and when i push items the array returns 0 length and it logged as empty but when i expand it it will show that it has the items.

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6NIj.png)

the code:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  await callback(array[index], index, array)
}
```

}

```
            asyncForEach(image, imageUpload => {
            RNFetchblob.fetch('POST', SERVICE_URL + 'uploadImage.php', {
                Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
                otherHeader : "foo",
                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
              }, [
                { name : 'image', filename : 'image.png', type:'image/png', data: imageUpload.data},
              ]).then((resp) => {
                const response = Object.values(resp)
                response.forEach(img => images.push(img))
              }).catch((err) => {

              })
            })
            console.log(images)
```

Comment: @Taplar Edited!

Comment: You're logging the array *long* before it is populated with items. I also recommend looking into `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @ChrisG i tried that, not working.

Comment: @سجادحيدر Show what you tried so we can point out the error you made.

Comment: @سجادحيدر My suggestion: https://pastebin.com/aLm2SqpG

Comment: @ChrisG i have done it, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you made is async, but the main code that calls it is not. Your `asyncForEach` returns a promise, and the code keeps running.

You need to put the logging command in a `.then()` attached to its result, or make your outer fuction async, which is mostly the same thing.

Another problem is that you're waiting for your promises in a loop, which means you won't start loading the second image until the first one is complete, etc. A much better alternative is to create an array of promises and pass them to `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(image.map(imageUpload => RNFetchblob.fetch(...).then(...))
  .then(() => console.log(images));
```

(One caveat is that if one of the uploads fails, the promise will reject immediately and print the results gathered so far, which could be empty. Note that the remaining uploads will still keep running, so it only affects the console output. It can be avoided by adding a `.catch` clause after `then`, but make sure you notify yourself of the error somehow.)

Comment: thank you but its not async anymore, What I'm trying to do is uploading the images, getting the images name, then adding item to the database with the images name passed with array https://imgur.com/a/dEzJRqw

Comment: It is still async. Using `async`/`await` is just alternative syntax for promises, the logic is still the same.

Comment: The second line is supposed to be `.then(images => console.log(images));`

Comment: It starts all uploads simultaneously (or several at a time, depending on how the browser decides to do it) and fills the array as the uploads complete. It is equivalent to your original code except for the simultaneous part - assuming you don't actually need it to be sequential for whatever reason.

Comment: Oh and if one of the uploads fails, it will print the array immediately, you can add a `catch` after `then` to avoid that.

Comment: Now the data will be added after uploading is done, i did it you saved my day thank you so much!